# Installing Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 on a MacBook Pro 7,1 (13 inch, Mid 2010)

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, macbook-pro

Was thinking of installing Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 on this old Mid 2010 MBP, and was wondering if there would be any issues with doing so. It is shown that the best option for this MBP would be Ubuntu 14.04, which is the reason why I am asking this question. However, I do want the latest version of Ubuntu possible, and therefore I am pointing towards 16.04.1, and specially Ubuntu GNOME.

So would this installation go smoothly, or will there be problems that would stop me from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu tends to be pretty generous about what it runs.  If you are uncomfortable with it you could always dual boot for awhile until you are sure everything works fine.  I don't personally own a Macbook so that's why I definitely say you should dualboot in case anything goes wrong on the install.  When installing select a custom install so you don't wipe the disk.  If you are sure everything is working you can always get rid of the OS X partition and resize the Ubuntu partition with something like gparted.